# Does the fundamental theorem of arithmetic imply well-ordering?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, induction

The standard proof of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic uses the well-ordering/induction axiom of natural numbers, is the converse true: does the fundamental theorem of arithmetic imply well-ordering/induction?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain sounds like a good direction.